Prevent upload file with same name and extension
Could some one help me to prevent uploading file with the same name and extension. By default Drupal add _0,_1.._n to the files with same name and extension. I am using filehash module to prevent uploading identical file which works great but I need to prevent file with the same name and extension regardless they might be different files.
